# In IIS Request Filtering, is the case of the string important?

Tags: iis, request-filtering

When in the Edit Filtering Rule dialog in IIS, is the case of the string, e.g. `cast(` important?

[image: Edit Filtering Rule]

We're seeing SQL injection attack attempts that have the string in various combinations of upper- and lower-case, like `cAsT(`. Do we need to be specific? I would expect that the module doesn't expect one to think of all the possible combinations but I can't find it clearly stated as the case in any of the online re

Comment: Most of the request filtering can be reimplemented via simple URL rewrite rules where you can easily use regular expressions. There is no need to dig further into request filtering configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The case of the filter strings is not important. A rule with `cast` should also work for `cAst` or `CAST`. This can easily be tested.

Comment: I expect it can be tested. I'd just like to be able to see the behaviour documented so that I can say to my manager, "there it is on page 66 para 3 of such and such a pdf"